# Using PHP Replace SPACES in URLS with %20

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm looking to replace all instances of spaces in urls with %20. How would I do that with regex?

Thank you!

Comment: is there any specific reason why it has to be done with regex? if its a URL you could use php's [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) method..

Comment: You should better describe your problem. See `parse_url` to only apply functions on the parts you want to or (if possible) build a valid URL from the beginning.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

No need for a regex here, if you just want to replace a piece of string by another: using [**`str_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/str_replace) should be more than enough :

```
$new = str_replace(' ', '%20', $your_string);
```

But, if you want a bit more than that, and you probably do, if you are working with URLs, you should take a look at the [**`urlencode()`**][2] function.

Comment: How to Replace # with / in codeignitor using routing.

Comment: I think this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240567/4027811 (actually below) is better, because change all critical signs for url, not only space.

Comment: Why is this replace even ":" and "/" from url? I'm having issues when trying to encode a URL to validate via `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`, because it only validates if the URL starts with "http".

Comment: This a terrible answer, str_replace comes with a lot of overhead. OP was looking to replace spaces in a URL, rawurlencode is the correct answer.

Answer (score 43):

I think you must use rawurlencode() instead urlencode() for your purpose.

sample

```
$image = 'some images.jpg';
$url   = 'http://example.com/'
```

With urlencode($str) will result

```
echo $url.urlencode($image); //http://example.com/some+images.jpg
```

its not change to %20 at all

but with rawurlencode($image) will produce

```
echo $url.rawurlencode(basename($image)); //http://example.com/some%20images.jpg
```

Comment: This is usually the best answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: For me, these outputs like this: `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome%20images.jpg` , my server has some problems or your answer is inaccurate maybe ?! Thanks.

Comment: Best answer than the accepted. Saved my day and lote of code.

Comment: I have the same problem ad @adrianTNT, I really don't get it !

Answer (score 40):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) rather than trying to implement your own. Be lazy.

Comment: He was, he asked instead of googling .)

Comment: Not lazy enough apparently :)

Comment: The only problem with this method is it turns all slashes and ampersands into entities also. My issue is only with spaces.

Yours, Lazy.

Comment: This isn't the best answer to the question even for lazy: rawurlencode()

Comment: Well it replaces a space with `+` - just not working.

Answer (score 18):

You've got several options how to do this, either:

- [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) - functions designed to encode URLs for http protocol
- [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) - "heavy machinery" string replace
- [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) - would have better performance than `str_replace()` when replacing multiple characters
- [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) use regular expressions (perl compatible)

#### [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Assuming that you want to replace `"\t"` and `" "` with `"%20"`:

```
$replace_pairs = array(
  "\t" => '%20',
  " " => '%20',
);
return strtr( $text, $replace_pairs)
```

#### [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

You've got few options here, either replacing just space `~ ~`, again replacing space and tab `~[ \t]~` or all [kinds of spaces](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) `~\s~`:

```
return preg_replace( '~\s~', '%20', $text);
```

Or when you need to replace string like this `"\t \t \t \t"` with just one `%20`:

```
return preg_replace( '~\s+~', '%20', $text);
```

<sub>I assumed that you really want to use manual string replacement and handle more types of whitespaces such as non breakable space (`&nbsp;`)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```php
    public static function normalizeUrl(string $url) {
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        return $parts['scheme'] .
            '://' .
            $parts['host'] .
            implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $parts['path'])));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('/ /', '%20', 'your string here');
```

you may also consider using

```
$result = urlencode($yourstring)
```

to escape other special characters as well