# How to generate url with strings?

Tags: php, string, email, url

I want to send via email link to generated page.

```
    function SendSubMail($email, $usr, $anime, $nr){
    $ling = "http://www.Anime.Maneku.pl/index.php?str=odcinek&anime=$anime&nr=$nr";
```

But string "$anime" allways have space and i get something like that

"http://www.Anime.Maneku.pl/index.php?str=odcinek&anime=Kyoukai no
Kanata���&nr=1"

but original link is "http://www.anime.maneku.pl/index.php?str=odcinek&anime=Kyoukai%20no%20Kanata%EF%BB%BF&nr=1"

and link dont works :c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP Replace SPACES in URLS with %20](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240556/using-php-replace-spaces-in-urls-with-20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using php's `urlencode()` method for your $anime variable.

```
$anime = urlencode($anime);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ling = "http://www.Anime.Maneku.pl/index.php?str=odcinek&anime=".$anime."&nr=".$nr;
```