# my url does not work correctly with spaces

Tags: php, mysql, variables

my url wheen i send with php & mysql i get not the full url 
i get only url to H&M and after that it stops just but i need the full in https link

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']); 
 $confirmcode = rand();

https://www.example.be/verification.php?username=$username&code=$confirmcode";
```

i get this wheen my username contains spaces `**https://www.example.be/verifcation.php?username=H&M** *Autos&code=716006183*`

Comment: remove spaces in $username

Comment: or replace spaces with some other symbol.....

Comment: @BilalAhmed but the user is registred with spaces his name is H&M Autos

Comment: you can change H&M-Autos and pass from url. when you fetch H&M-Autos then you can convert into H&M Autos.. space replace with - sign

Comment: @BilalAhmed it is a automatic system wheen user is registred he receive an email with link where the email is confirmed. so i can't do it for every user

Comment: i am refer you this post.. this post will help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240556/using-php-replace-spaces-in-urls-with-20

Comment: it working i just changed the username to email email have never spaces lol thank you for help anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you escaping something that goes into a URL using MySQL functions?

You should be using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$username = urlencode($_POST['username']);
```

Not all escaping functions do the same thing. Pay very close attention to context.

Comment: If you liked it, give it a +1. Accept the answer when you're confident it worked as a signal to others in the same jam.

Comment: i can't give nothing because  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." i get this msg but i replaced the username to email and emails have never spaces

Comment: That's only for very new accounts. Accepting answers signals to others that you're willing to review their work, so you're more likely to get responses in the future. Glad that worked!